Can't connect view to controller on rails guide
Currently following the 7.1.3.2 guide of "Getting Started with Rails" listed on the rails site. I'm struggling with the step of routing a view with an h1 of "Hello, Rails". Server doesn't show the header and instead has the default view of the rails logo.
Controller:
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end

view named "index":
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>

routes:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "articles#index"

  get "/articles", to: "articles#index"
end

I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing as I have followed the guide to a tee as well as scrapped and remade the project a few times.

Did you restart the server after changing the config/routes.rb? I am asking, because changes to files in the config folder require a restart to take effect.

Try root to: "articles#index"

@spickermann in development Rails actually "hot swaps" configuration files like routes.rb. I'm not 100% but I think it tied to config.cache_classes .

@HarshKumar root "articles#index" is a shorthand and does the exact same thing.  https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.3.2/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-root
